# What is the equation for the pressure at which neutrons can no longer be supported by neutron degeneracy pressure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle, neutrons

What is the equation for the pressure at which neutrons can no longer be supported by neutron degeneracy pressure? At which point they would collapse into each other.

There seems to be one for electrons: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_degeneracy_pressure
but not for neutrons.

The only information about neutrons is based on weather stellar mass objects will collapse to neutron stars or to black holes, however there seem to be no equations for just the neutrons resistance to collapse. Like not based on gravity, or stars.

Comment: See [this](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Term_Reports/John_Timlin.pdf).

Comment: Do you understand what happens when electron-degenerate matter collapses to neutron degenerate matter? In particular the importance of the Fermi-energy to the question of which state is favored?

Comment: Thank you Demosthene. And to dmckee: well I thought I did until I looked up fermi-energy. I understand that gravitational pressure causes it to become energetically favorable for the electrons to combine with protons to become neutrons, the opposition that gravity overcomes is provided by the Pauli exclusion principal. Beyond that not a ton.